# How can I remove the right border for a UL/LI element in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, border, html-lists

I have a problem with all versions of Internet Explorer. I have an `ul` with `li` elements that have a right border. You can see what it looks like at the bottom of [this page](http://demo.jimbarraud.com/manifest/) ("Elsewhere").

The problem is not particular to this page, but to all similar HTML setups.

[Here's what it looks like in other browsers](http://gyazo.com/b15fb110a92821b72b6723342a0de620)

[Here's what it looks like in IE](http://gyazo.com/53782c655282c235b828c838bfacd600)

How do I tell IE to remove that right border?

Comment: Hmm, i don't see it, it looks ok to me in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the :last-child selector to set a border none on the last list item.  Unfortunately, all IE versions except 9 (and 10 RC) do not support that style.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35

Why not just use the first-child selector (disable the left border) and set a left border on all other list items?  Seems to be a much safer route, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that idea as well. But because this is some PHP dynamically generated through multiple files (Wordpress, actually), I wanted to know if there was a way to do it with HTML/CSS.